# React-router: Using <Link> as clickable data table row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm new to using ReactJS and react-router. I want a clickable table row and something like the following setup:

```
<Link to=“#”>
<tr>
    <td>{this.props.whatever1}</td>
    <td>{this.props.whatever2}</td>
    <td>{this.props.whatever3}</td>
</tr>
</Link>
```

but I know you can't put `<a>` tags between the `<tbody>` and `<tr>` tags. How else can I accomplish this?

PS: I prefer not to use jQuery if possible.

Comment: "clickable" is very broad. Do you want to add a hyperlink to another page, or do you want to run some Javascript code when clicked? If the former, just add an `<a>` inside the `<td>`, where it belongs. If it's the latter, you can add an onClick listener like so `<tr onClick={this.handleClick}>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just use onClick?

```
var ReactTable = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(e) {
    this.router.transitionTo('index');
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Full Detail</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
                <td>{user.name}</td>
                <td>{user.age}</td>
                <td>{details}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Then you can't use right click options, such as open in new tab. Which might be useful especially with tables.

Comment: Very few apps use context menu's appropriately and are almost impossible to use well in mobile. You should rethink your UX if you're trying to use right-click in a react-app

Comment: The above point wasn't about a context menu... it's a common pattern to "Open in new Tab/Window" - whether you do that with a right click, cmd/ctrl-click, long press or whatever.

Comment: @EricHodonsky the onClick handler prevents <ctrl>+<click> from opening the link in a new tab. It's not necessarily about context menu's. Sure I could detect `event.ctrlKey` in the onClick function and use `window.open`, but I was hoping for a native way to accomplish this. Maybe the whole concept of a clickable row link is invalid anyway, maybe we should apply the link to each table column. A little repetitive but probably more accurate.

Comment: It inhibits power users and disabled users

Answer (score 25):

`onClick` works, but sometimes you need an actual `<a>` tag for various reasons:

- Accessibility
- Progressive enhancement (if script is throwing an error, links still work)
- Ability to open a link in new tab
- Ability to copy the link

Here's an example of a Td component that accepts `to` prop:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Td({ children, to }) {
  // Conditionally wrapping content into a link
  const ContentTag = to ? Link : 'div';

  return (
    <td>
      <ContentTag to={to}>{children}</ContentTag>
    </td>
  );
}
```

Then use the component like this:

```
const users = this.props.users.map((user) =>
      <tr key={user.id}>
        <Td to={`/users/${user.id}/edit`}>{user.name}</Td>
        <Td to={`/users/${user.id}/edit`}>{user.email}</Td>
        <Td to={`/users/${user.id}/edit`}>{user.username}</Td>
      </tr>
    );
```

Yes, you'll have to pass `to` prop multiple times, but at the same you have more control over the clickable areas and you may have other interactive elements in the table, like checkboxes.

Comment: but you will end up with invalid html (div as children of tr)

Comment: Just checked. Div inside td is legal:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/l24ioflyjjxjuq6/Screenshot%202017-02-28%2010.40.59.png?dl=0

Comment: Ah I misread. I thought the code would end up having div inside tr

Comment: how do you implement it for clicking on the entire row? wrapping <tr> with another tag breaks table style.

Comment: @DragonKnight you can probably use `Link` and style it with `display: table-row`. I haven't tried it though

Comment: only contents (eg text) will be linked, not the row

Answer (score 5):

This answers is based on @Igor Barbasin suggestion. This will add the link to the whole row instead of just the content and we also don't need to wrap all the individual 'td' element with 'Link'.

```css
.table-row {
  display: table-row
}
```

```js
export default function Table() {
  return (
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {/* treats the link element as a table row element */}
            <Link className="table-row">
                <td>Noname</td>
            </Link>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `useHistory()` hook:

Declare:

```
const history = useHistory();
```

and use it with `<tr>` or `<td>` tag:

```
<tr onClick={() => history.push("/yoururl")}>
    <td>{this.props.whatever1}</td>
    <td>{this.props.whatever2}</td>
    <td>{this.props.whatever3}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
{shipment.assets.map((i, index) => (
                              <tr
                                style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                                onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                              >
                                <td>{index + 1}</td>
                                <td>{i._id}</td>
                                <td>{i.status}</td>
                                <td></td>
                              </tr>
                            ))}
```

Comment: Please add more details to your code. This does not help much to others who are looking at your answer for the first time